# Data does not persist when dyno is restarted in Heroku?

Tags: heroku, strapi

I have deployed Strapi headless CMS on Heroku free tier and tried to use it both with MongoDB and Postgres databases, whenever I restart the dyno e.g. during deployment - all the data created thus far is not persisted?

I tried rebuilding Strapi locally and I cannot reproduce the behaviour.

I am using free tier for hosting of Strapi as well as free tier of Heroku Postgres.

Comment: That's what's supposed to happen. The file system on a dyno is ephemeral. You need to move any state to the DB, *outside* of the dyno itself.

Comment: The data in question are stored in Heroku Postgres, which is a DB, right?

Comment: Yes, Postgres is a DB. If the data are disappearing on a simple dyno restart, that's *not* where they're being stored.

Comment: Alright, that then answers a part of my question, wondering where does Strapi save data if it does not put it in DB.

Comment: Can you define data. Are you referring to the content types or actual rows of data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you created your project with `--quickstart` which is not Postgres, it is SQLite. Can you please check your `config/environments/*/database.json` files and ensure you have PostgreSQL setup?

All model configs are stored in files meaning you will not be able to create, edit, or delete new models, fields, components while using Heroku. All data (content) is saved to the database.

https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/guides/deployment.html#heroku